# Elasticsearch mapping error

Tags: elasticsearch

Why is this mapping setup (part of my index template) giving me this error:

```
    "error": "MapperParsingException[mapping [properties]]; nested: MapperParsingException[Root type mapping not empty after parsing! Remaining fields:   [cache : {type=string}] [metatag.description : {index=no, type=string}] [title : {type=string}] [content : {analyzer=autocomplete_shingles_analyzer, type=string}] [url : {type=string}] [tstamp : {format=dateOptionalTime, index=no, type=date}] [anchor : {type=string}] [segment : {type=string}] [digest : {type=string}] [host : {type=string}] [boost : {type=string}] [id : {type=string}] [metatag.keywords : {index=no, type=string}]]; ",
   "status": 400
```

Mapping setup, part of my index template

```
    POST /_template/dev3index
{
  "template": "dev*",
  "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete_shingles_filter": {
          "type": "shingle",
          "min_shingle_size": 2,
          "max_shingle_size": 5,
          "output_unigrams": true
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete_shingles_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
          "lowercase",
          "autocomplete_shingles_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "anchor": {
        "type": "string"
        },
        "boost": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "cache": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "content": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete_shingles_analyzer"
        },
        "digest": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "host": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "metatag.description": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "no"
        },
        "metatag.keywords": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "no"
        },
        "segment": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "tstamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dateOptionalTime",
          "index": "no"
         },
         "url": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm using the Sense ES plugin.

I'm using Nutch to crawl a small number of sites, so I'm trying to setup the index before ES does it. I'm using ES 1.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct child of "mappings" should be the name of a type, with the "properties" element nested beneath that. I've included an example below where I have inserted a type called "my_type":

```
{
   "template":"dev*",
   "settings":{
      "number_of_shards":1,
      "number_of_replicas":0,
      "analysis":{
         "filter":{
            "autocomplete_shingles_filter":{
               "type":"shingle",
               "min_shingle_size":2,
               "max_shingle_size":5,
               "output_unigrams":true
            }
         },
         "analyzer":{
            "autocomplete_shingles_analyzer":{
               "type":"custom",
               "tokenizer":"whitespace",
               "filter":[
                  "lowercase",
                  "autocomplete_shingles_filter"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings":{
      "my_type":{
         "properties":{
            "anchor":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "boost":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "cache":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "content":{
               "type":"string",
               "analyzer":"autocomplete_shingles_analyzer"
            },
            "digest":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "host":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "id":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "metatag.description":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"no"
            },
            "metatag.keywords":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"no"
            },
            "segment":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "title":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "tstamp":{
               "type":"date",
               "format":"dateOptionalTime",
               "index":"no"
            },
            "url":{
               "type":"string"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: awesome! something so simple - needed fresh eyes